# ASP.NET C# Add/Update User to Role

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles

Hi all I have a page that shows Accommodation info and then the UserID of the person that created that information in a DetailsView.

I also have a button that should look at that that UserID and when clicked take that userID convert it to a username so that then I can use that username to change the persons role to a renter. However I am unsure using C# how I can grab the UserID from details view do the conversion and update the role. Any ideas?

Mark

@Tim

Here is the code I have added:

```
public partial class adminonly_approval : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void DetailsView1_ItemCommand(Object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e){
    if (e.CommandName == "SetToRenter")
    {
        // if UserID is in second row:
        DetailsViewRow row = DetailsView1.Rows[9];

        // Get the Username from the appropriate cell.
        // In this example, the Username is in the second cell  
        String UserID = row.Cells[9].Text;
        MembershipUser memUser = Membership.GetUser(UserID);
        Roles.AddUserToRole(memUser.UserName, "renter");
    }
}
```

I Have added a button on the page below the details view and set the commandName to SetToRenter. When I click the button though it isn't changing the roles. Im new to ASP and C# but need this feature for a university assignment. 
Any Idea?

Answer (score 12):

[Membership.GetUser(UserId)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152019.aspx)

```
MembershipUser memUser = Membership.GetUser(UserId);
Roles.AddUserToRole(memUser.UserName, "Renter");
```

[Roles.AddUserToRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole.aspx)

Here is an example on how to get values of your DetailsView's BoundFields:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.itemcommand.aspx

You should set the Button's CommandName to its function and handle the DetailsView.ItemCommand Event in codebehind. There you can get your UserID in the following way:

```
void DetailsView1_ItemCommand(Object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e){
    if (e.CommandName == "SetToRenter")
    {
        // if UserID is in second row:
        DetailsViewRow row = DetailsView1.Rows[1];

        // Get the Username from the appropriate cell.
        // In this example, the Username is in the second cell  
        String UserID = row.Cells[1].Text;
        MembershipUser memUser = Membership.GetUser(UserId);
        Roles.AddUserToRole(memUser.UserName, "Renter");
    }
}
```

As Cem has mentioned you should set the DetailsView's [DataKey Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.datakey.aspx). Then you can also get the PK of the current record in the following way:

```
// Get the ArrayList objects that represent the key fields
ArrayList keys = (ArrayList)(DetailsView1.DataKey.Values).Keys;
// Get the key field for the current record. 
String UserID = keys[0].ToString();
```

Even simpler is the shortcut [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.selectedvalue.aspx) of the DetailsView:

```
String UserID= DetailsView1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the reply, I see that gets the current UsersID rather than one in the details view UserID field any idea how I do that?

Comment: @Mark: that does not get the UserID of the current user. It simply shows the way to add a user to a role when you have the UserID. You should show us some code or tell us about the problems you have to get the UserID.

Comment: Also DataKey work as well. I mean you don't have to find `UserID`'s cell in DetailsView. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.datakey.aspx

Comment: @Tim I have added the code to my original post that I added and am having some problems. I see this other code you added after cem mentioned it but you say that gets the PK but that is Accom_ID in this case not UserID

Comment: @Mark: you could always use my first method, that you've copied into your question. But you haven't mentioned what kind of problems you have. I doubt that it is actually the 10th cell in the 10th row of your detailsview. I would assume that it's the 10th row but the second cell. `String UserID = row.Cells[1].Text;`

Comment: @Mark: Almost forgotten- you don't need to add an CommandName to your button if the button is not part of the DetailsView. You should simply handle the Button-Click event.