# ASP.NET C# Add User to a Role

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles

Hi All I a Details View containing UserID and other attributes. I want on button click to be able to update the UserID shown with the Role Renter. I therefore set a button with the CommandName SetToRenter and have the following code in the C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;

public partial class adminonly_approval : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void DetailsView1_ItemCommand(Object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e){
    if (e.CommandName == "SetToRenter")
    {
        DetailsViewRow row = DetailsView1.Rows[0];
        String UserID = row.Cells[0].Text;
        MembershipUser memUser = Membership.GetUser(UserID);
        Roles.AddUserToRole(memUser.UserName, "renter");
    }
}

}
```

On click of the button it just refreshes the code and is failing to set the role to renter.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any error? Make sure you have renter role. I am not sure if case-sensitivity is an issue or not but check that as well. Also do you have to call GetUser to get username? I think you should be having that in your DetailsView, don't you?

Comment: Looks like you posted this question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544298/asp-net-c-add-update-user-to-role Please avoid duplicating.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get into the ItemCommand method when you debug your code, if you do, thne perhaps if you check the database, the "renter" role had been added to the asp.net roles table for memUser but does not show the change on the DetailsView for some obscure reason.