# how to add roles to asp.net when you have webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am beginner in ASP.NET, and I need help to create user roles and identity. Until now, I have create few Webforms (Registration page, Login page...) but I don't know how to manage user roles. I want to bind users with roles, and identities. I saw few examples how to do it, but it didn't work for me. Thank you in advance for help.

I have just tried to enable asp.net configuration option in VS 2013 (as it is described here http://alireza-afshar.com/wordpress/?p=74) but I got error message:

*There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store. 
The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0d4c4367\763dc453\hash' is denied.*

Could please someone help me with this? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: this could be work for you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544298/asp-net-c-sharp-add-update-user-to-role#answer-5544433](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544298/asp-net-c-sharp-add-update-user-to-role#answer-5544433)

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I will take a look on the links you gave me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Aspnet_regsql.exe tool also that article will be helpful for you http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs

Comment: ASP.Net Membership Provider created using aspnet_regsql.exe has been deprecated. If you want to go that route, you want to look at  [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx). However, you want to use ASP.Net Identity if you are developing a new project.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.Net comes with Membership Provider since .Net 2.0, so you do not have to reinvent the wheel.

The latest version is called [ASP.NET Identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elvYJ.png). You can look at it by creating a new Web Forms application.

[image]

[image]

### More Resources for Identity in WebForm

- [ASP.NET Identity with webforms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/751897/ASP-NET-Identity-with-webforms)
- [Adding ASP.NET Identity to an Empty or Existing Web Forms Project](http://Adding%20ASP.NET%20Identity%20to%20an%20Empty%20or%20Existing%20Web%20Forms%20Project)

Comment: I can really relate to this question regarding Identity with Web Forms. I am not used to working with EF, for example, and I cannot find a good tutorial on Identity that doesn't involve MVC...

Comment: @IrishChieftain I agree that most Identity tutorial are based on MVC. ASP.Net Identity with OWIN authentication is pretty new in WebForm, so we might have to wait for few more months in order to see those tutorials. I added few links in the answer.